# How to run unit tests in multi-module maven setup if i put the tests in a separate module?

Tags: java, testing, maven, multi-module, spock

i have created a multi-module maven project and i am trying to write and execute some tests on specific modules. I am trying to put all test-code into a separate module, but i am wondering if this is the correct way and if so how to i setup the maven build/test cycle so mvn install will use these tests?

Comment: The simple answer is don't put the unit tests in a separate module.  Put them in the same module as the code they are testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) test classes belong to the directory `src/test/java` and required resources to `src/test/resources`. On the long term it will make your life easier by following the rules, especially when you work on many different projects (where you sometimes can not define alternative structures). In this setup the test cases are automatically invoked by `mvn install` or `mvn test`.

You find more informations about the surefire-plugin (responsible for executing the tests) [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/).